# Sharepoint 2010 tutorials

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am a c# web developer and company has gone sharepoint and want me to do a sharepoint website. Any great free sharepoint downloads, articles and/or tutorials out there for a sharepoint beginner? Kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best place to learn this is MSDN. Here's the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb931739%28v=office.12%29.aspx) .

You will get exposed to almost all the aspects of sharepoint.